# Ubuntu installation failed, and now can't find hard-drive. What happened, and is it fixable?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, grub-efi

Noob here. I think Ubuntu has (soft)bricked my new laptop.

After playing with a live USB, I decided to dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04. I did the partitioning through Windows 10, and then tried to install Ubuntu. I followed appropriate instructions for EFI partitioning, but the custom installation screen wouldn't let me click next, so I gave up and went the automatic installation route instead.

I selected dual-boot and encryption, then installed Ubuntu successfully. I had to reboot for something or another, and was able to select either OS.

However, when booting up the next day, I no longer had any OS. It boots directly into Setup. I believe the difference might be because I shut the computer all the way down, or from something to do with Fast Startup being on, but that's a guess. I never finished setting up encryption, so I don't think that's a factor.

I can get Ubuntu working just fine from a live USB, but when trying to install it only sees the 8GB USB, but not the harddrive. Same if I run queries from Terminal. ([Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23983220/) is the boot info printout I got while troubleshooting myself. A more recent one is in the comments.) Same if I use my Windows recovery disk to access Microsoft's troubleshooting tools, and query via Command Prompt.

I've seen related issues, but nothing that seems to apply to me. Do I just need to access my boot partition and get Grub installed correctly? Is the problem from me not turning off Fast Startup through Windows before installing, or because I chose encryption, or something else?

Even Windows system restore can only reinstall windows, but not repair the boot sector. Tools for that expect to see a hard-drive, but don't. So, I figured I'd stop guessing and ask "what happened?".

I'm lost enough here that I'm not even sure I'm asking the right questions, so feel free to suggest better ones. I've been trying to figure things out for a couple weeks, and am only now caving and asking for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please boot the Ubuntu installer or emergency disk and run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @RodSmith thanks.

The results from Boot Info Script are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23982288/). However, I'll note that it [had a hiccup](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23982417/) and had to use "busybox awk" instead of "gawk".

I don't remember what script I used when I was poking around before asking the question, but I still have the file, so I'll edit the question to include a link to that. It looks like it provides a little more info.

Comment: Boot Info Script is not detecting your hard disk. It could be you've booted using an older emergency disk that lacks the appropriate drivers; or it could be your hard disk is an unusual model (probably an NVMe or similar disk) that Boot Info Script is not yet configured to scan; or it could be your main hard disk has failed (disk failure, cable unplugged, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above, I strongly suspect that my hard drive simply failed, and the fact that it happened the day after I installed Ubuntu was a coincidence. It is a new laptop, and factory [burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn-in) is sometimes necessary because [bathtub curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) mean lots of failures happen early. So, the fact that I was more likely to play with a new PC upped the odds of such an [apparently improbable coincidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_law).

I called Asus, and they replaced the hard drive under warranty. When it came back, the receipt simply said "Problem: HDD Bad Track". I've since reinstalled Ubuntu, and have shut down and restarted several times without issue. Grub has loaded each time, and let me boot into both Ubuntu and Windows 10 successfully.

The only major thing I did differently during installations was turn off Fast Startup in Windows. (I also checked both the "download updates while installing" and the "install third party software" check boxes, and only tried the "Install along side Windows" installation option, instead of first tinkering the "something else" option. (I didn't want to worry about whether I was doing the correct thing for EFI partitions, and whether I was overwriting the device selected for boot loader installation.) I didn't encrypt the home folder this time either, on the off chance that that had something to do with not being able to find the hard drive before.) But, I think that's my paranoia talking, and not a likely cause of the problem.